# Was Deborah Voorhees cast due to her surname?

Tags: casting, friday-the-13th, friday-the-13th-a-new-beginning

In [*Friday the 13th: A New Beginning*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089173/?ref_=tttr_tr_tt), the character of Tina is portrayed by an actress named [Deborah Voorhees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debi_Sue_Voorhees).  She coincidentally shares the same surname (even spelled the same) as Jason Voorhees, who is the main antagonist in the majority of the Friday the 13th films.

Deborah Voorhees

[image: Deborah Voorhees]

Is there any evidence that filmmakers cast Deborah Voorhees due to her last name?  Did her last name have *anything* to do with her being awarded the role of Tina?

Comment: Voorhees isn't a super-unusual surname: Wikipedia lists [18 famous Voorheeses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voorhees_(surname)), plus six fictional ones and a bunch of Vorhieses, a Voorhis, a Vories and a bunch of places named after them.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Sure, but were any of the people on that list ever cast or audition for a _Friday the 13th_ film?

Comment: @steelerssquirrel Yes -- Deborah! :-P

Comment: @DavidRicherby Hahaha!  Touche ;)

Comment: Congratulations, this question is the winner of the [corresponding topic challenge](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4192/49).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

While she wasn't cast due to her name, she certainly got to the auditions part due to the name as per this [interview](http://www.fridaythe13thfranchise.com/2011/04/interview-debi-sue-voorhees-tina-new.html):

> **(DAN PETERS):** Being that you share the last name of the infamous killer Jason Voorhees, do you think that helped you secure your role in the franchise?
>
> **(DEBI SUE):** It certainly helped me get the interview. That was one of the first things the casting agent mentioned when I came in. “***We knew the second we saw that name we had to audition you***.”

Comment: It's possible that the casting director was just making a joke.

Comment: It is indeed possible that the casting director made a joke but it's too good an opportunity to pass up when a person's name consists of two of your movie's character's names "Sue" and "Voorhees" that they might have just wanted to see her firsthand! The movie role was a good side-eefect from it! :D

Answer (score -1):

The director had directed a soft core porn called High Rise in the 70's without the studio realizing it.  He decided to change the actress because of her breast size and her last name was a happy coincidence.

Fun fact: the original girl for that role was cast in the next F13 film.  Part 6 is known to show no nudity at all.  They asked her if she would and she said its not in my contract so she didn't.  She would've in part 6.  She was the girl in the winnebago.

Watch Crystal Lake Memories and it explains it all.  Its a documentary that covers every movie including the remake.  It interview Cast, Directors and Producers.

Comment: any proof for this?

Comment: You make a bunch of claims in your answer, please [edit] to include proper citations or links.